# Mysql query to find rows with specific columns data duplicated

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm about to clean mess that my users left me by recording duplicate data in table `users`:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|id  |name |surname |otherdata                      |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|99  |John |Doe     |Lorem ipsum...                 |
|1199|John |Doé     |may and may not be the same... |
|1583|Doe  |John    |irrelevant data...             |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I need query to **show me** (I don't need auto fix) duplicate entries like this presented.

Is this feasible by using `mysql` only?

Note two `e`'s. (I guess `%LIKE%` will do the job before `=`).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google:  "MySQL Levenshtein distance".

Comment: I know about levenshtein distance. I simply don't know how to utilize it.

Comment: I'm afraid you've got your work cut out for you. :-(

Answer (score 0):

if i got you right .You can try it..

```
  SELECT users.name name, users.surname surname,count(users.id) count
                           FROM users GROUP BY users.name,users.surname
```

in output you recieve like that

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|name |surname |count   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|John |Doe     |2       |
|Doe  |John    |1       |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

You can see John Doe in you tablу, 2 times